# internel server error 500

Tags: http

I made a web application that I connect to it from a mobile device 
and I used Ajax Request Object but the status of the object returned data is 500

and after search I found that this means Internel Server Error 500

Is there any suggestions what may be the reason ??

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should look your server's error log. It will give you informations about the error (depeding the verbose level given in the configuration)

Comment: Hello, I saw the error log c:\windows\log files\httperr\httperr1.log (windows 7) and I found this error 2010-06-10 10:48:48 ::1%0 49802 ::1%0 2869 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle - – 
Do you know what this means ??

Comment: looks like iis webserver, I don't know it at all. Try google timer_connectionIlde.

Comment: I searched for it and found that it means too long to connect with server but
I think this is not my error due to

1- when I run my application from VS it works well
2- when I run my application from localhost in browser it doesnot work (I am using MVC and pointing to action)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the data sent and the data type expected do not match.

Comment: all what I send to the server is am image